# HTML image that capture no space in UI

Tags: html

I have an image in my HTML page as shown below -

```
  <img style="width: 0; height: 0" src="demoImage.jpg" />
```

Though, I have set width and height to zero, it's still capturing some space in UI, which I don't want. Can anyone please help me to fix it?

[NB: I cant remove this image though it is invisible, because it is used for image load testing.]

Thanks,
Kartic

Comment: Maybe try to remove margin?

Comment: try adding px after 0 in width and height

Comment: I think image cannot have .jsp extension.

Comment: margin, padding didn't work. Tried using px, but still no luck.

Comment: Oh, sorry! it's by mistake, it should be jpg. Edited my question.

Comment: @abhinav Why do you think that would make a difference?

Comment: Image sources can be a dynamic web page, if the said source is going to generate the image. So php,jsp,etc are all valid.

Comment: Yeah! display: none worked. Thank you so very much Piotr Czarnecki. May be you can post your answer so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kartic like I wrote in comment **display: none** should be the best for you :)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to use the image for tracking/etc, the best way around is to position the image off screen. like this:

```
 <img style="width: 0px; height: 0px; position:absolute; left:-100px; top:-100px;" src="demoImage.jsp" />
```